# Ruby: Combining simple array elements

Tags: ruby, arrays, text

```
     array = [
     ["sean", "started", "shift", "at", "10:30:00"],
     ["anna", "started", "shift", "at", "11:00:00"],
     ["sean", "started", "shift", "at", "10:41:45"],
     ["anna", "finished", "shift", "at", "11:30:00"],
     ["sean", "finished", "shift", "at", "10:48:45"],
     ["sean", "started", "shift", "at", "11:31:00"],
     ["sean", "finished", "shift", "at", "11:40:00"]
     ]
```

Few things to consider

1. if you look at sean's entries - there are 2 entries for 'start times' one at 10:30:00 and also at 10:41:45 . The system can record multiple 'start times' but only one 'Finished' time. The logic is to pair  first 'started' & first 'finished' and combine them.
2. How to skip the duplicated 'start time' entries (such as Sean's) and get a desired output as below...

   array = [
    ["sean", "started", "shift", "at", "10:30:00", "finished", "shift", "at", "10:48:45"],
    ["anna", "started", "shift", "at", "11:00:00", "finished", "shift", "at", "11:30:00"],
    ["sean", "started", "shift", "at", "11:31:00", "finished", "shift", "at", "11:40:00"]
     ]

Theres no easy way is it?

Comment: You most likely should use objects to deal with this instead of arrays.

Comment: pretty interesting... New thing to learn as I am new bee..

Comment: For your purposes, you wouldn't even need full-fledged classes. You could use structs. `Shift = Struct.new(:name, :start_time, :end_time)`. Then, an example shift: `first_shift = Shift.new("Sean", "10:30:00", "10:48:45")`. A lot cleaner end result.

Answer (score 1):

```
array.group_by(&:first).map do |person, events| 
  events.chunk { |_, event_type| event_type }.each_slice(2).map do |(_, (start, _)), (_, (finish, _))|  
    %W(#{p} started shift at #{start[4]} finished shift at #{finish[4]}) 
  end
end

# => [
# => ["sean", "started", "shift", "at", "10:30:00", "finished", "shift", "at", "10:48:45"],
# => ["sean", "started", "shift", "at", "11:31:00", "finished", "shift", "at", "11:40:00"],
# => ["anna", "started", "shift", "at", "11:00:00", "finished", "shift", "at", "11:30:00"]
# => ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
started = {}
result = []
array.each do |name, *event|
  if event[0] == "started" && !started[name]
    result << (started[name] = [name] + event)
  elsif event[0] == "finished" && started[name]
    started[name].concat(event)
    started[name] = nil
  end
end
result
```

**EDIT** Completely agree with fotanus, BTW.

**EDIT2** Forgot to change a variable name. Also: logic. You take each row in turn. `started` will contain any records that have started but not yet finished. So, take a row; if it's "started", and only if we don't know that that person already started, remember the start. If it's "finished", and only if we already know the person has started, finish up the record by appending the finish info.

Comment: hi Amadan, so whats the logic here?